# The role and the meaning of the “of”

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

Consider the two sentences below

> It is of crucial importance that we make more use of technology if we are to make progress.

and

> It is crucially important that we make more use of technology if we are to make progress.

1. What is the grammatical role of "of" in the the first sentence?
2. What is difference between the two sentences in meaning and emphasizing?

Comment: @Downvoter It is expected that you drop me a line if there is a problem with my question so, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good question.  Some contributors to this site would recommend you try Stack Exchange's English for Language Learners website, but I'm willing to attempt an answer to your question.

First, the *of* is a preposition in a prepositional phrase, as in your example, "of crucial importance." Let me suggest also the phrases "of moderate interest,"  "of weird proportions," and "of primary concern," as in

> It [the statue] was of weird proportions, but it came together nicely."
>
> It [the project] was of moderate interest to me, but I participated anyway."
>
> It [the coat] was of bright color, but it was not garish in any way."

I guess you could say that grammatically, each of the above prepositional phrases functions as a *predicate adjective*.  A simple definition of a predicate adjective is a word or words that modify (or predicate something about) the subject of the sentence, as in "The dress is *blue*," or "The dress is *of blue color*." Your *of crucial importance* and *crucially important* are also predicate adjectives, each of which predicates something about the subject, *it*.

Regarding the above sentences, if you were to ask "What kind of it was it?" you could also say, "It was weirdly proportioned," "It was moderately interesting," or "It was brightly colored."

In meaning, the two ways of describing "it" are essentially identical.

Emphasis, on the other hand, derives primarily from the nonverbal, not grammatical, realm.  I'll use bold print to illustrate:

> "It [the statue] was of **weird** proportions, but it came together nicely."
>
> It [the project] was of **moderate** interest to me, but I participated in it anyway."
>
> It [the coat] was of bright **color**, but it was not garish in any way."

Similarly,

> "The statue was weirdly **proportioned**, but it came together nicely."
>
> "The project was **moderately** interesting, but I participated anyway."
>
> "The coat was brightly **colored**, but it was not garish in any way."

You could also put the nonverbal emphasis on *weirdly*, *interesting*, or *brightly*, depending on how you'd like to express yourself.

By the way, in comparing the two sets of sentences above, you could say idiomatically, "Six of one; half dozen of the other."  In other words, they are two ways of saying the same thing.

Back to your sentences:

> "It is of **crucial** importance that we make more use of technology . . .."
>
> "It is crucially **important** that we make more use of technology . . .."

You could also put the nonverbal emphasis on *important* or *crucially*, depending on which word you want to emphasize.  The meaning stays the same.

If you were to say either sentence in a noncommittal, monotone, unemotional way, your audience would not likely remember what you said.  On the other hand, if you emphasize a word here and there, they'll likely remember that you were at least committed to what you had to say, even if they don't remember exactly what you said!

Comment: I put the question in Stack Exchange's English for Language Learners, but I haven't had an answer yet. However, I am so happy because your answer is dead-on. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad you went on to 'of is a preposition _in a prepositional phrase_' , because 'of importance' (like 'of interest', 'of ... proportions', 'of (a) ... colour') seem more cohesive than say 'of the boy's' or 'of England'. There is a degree of collocation. We cannot replace 'The measures were considered necessary' with 'The measures were considered of necessity' or 'They were vital' with 'They were of vitalness'.

Comment: @AbbasAmiri:  You're welcome.  I am glad you found my answer helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. "of" is a preposition.
2. Both sentences emphasize the same point in slightly different manners. Think of the two as interchangeable. The difference grammatically is:

   1. > of crucial importance

      *of* — preposition,
      *crucial* — adjective,
      *importance* — noun
   2. > crucially important

      *crucially* — adverb,
      *important* — noun

Comment: *Crucially* is not an adjective, and there is no *importance* in the second case. Too much copypasta.

Comment: My mistake, I wrote the wrong part of speech. Is now fixed.

Comment: _Crucially_ is not considered an adverb either, in this type of construction, by the grammatical school I subscribe to - but a secondary modifier (here, a modifier of an adjective).

Comment: Adverb in English serves as a modifier of an adjective, not exclusively though.

Comment: ... according to a school I do not subscribe to (the _adverb-dustbin school_). See Sussex University discussion at https://www.sussex.ac.uk/webteam/gateway/file.php?name=essay---parts-of-speech.pdf&site=1 for an introduction to the debate (though I prefer further refinements, as referenced elsewhere on this site).

Comment: You **still** suggest that the word "importance" is present in the second sentence - **it isn't**!

Comment: My apologies. It was a typo.